# Notepad++ REGEX 3 or 4 digits at the end of string

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to match the amount of money that is at the very last portion of the string. Some amount of money are in thousands e.g. 1,200.00 and some are only hundreds, e.g. 450.95. The string looks like this "March6March7Globe-Gmovies3dTaguigCity320.00".

Once match, I want to replace the entire string by just the matching value. E.g.

```
March6March7Globe-Gmovies3dTaguigCity320.00
March6March7Globe-Gmovies3dTaguigCity1,320.00
```

becomes

```
320.00
1,320.00
```

Why is my pattern only matching the thousands matching and not the hundreds? Thanks.

Here's my pattern:

```
(.*)(\d{1}?\,?\d{3}\.\d{2})
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is happening? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. … … P.S. I see only two different patterns in your sample data: 1000 > N ≥ 100 and 10000 > N ≥ 1000.  There’s no point in listing 27 examples if there are only two different cases.

Comment: Hi @Scott, I've edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: (.*?)([\d\.\,]+)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try: `(.*?)((\d,)?\d{3}\.\d{2})`

Here, the `(*.?)` is like `(.*)`, but minimally (the shortest matching string).
The comma doesn't have to be escaped.

Comment: Can you explain why this works  when `(.*)((\d,)?\d{3}\.\d{2})` doesn’t?

Comment: If you take the regex `(.*)((\d,)?\d{3}\.\d{2})` and as example string `City1,320.00`, then
the first capturing group `(.*)` matches `City1,`, because it's the _longest match_. 
The `(\d,)?` doesn't match here (the 1st group is before that and thus matches first), because it is optional. You could say the `.*` is "greedier".
With `(.*?)((\d,)?\d{3}\.\d{2})` the greedy part matches _the shortest string_ `City` and `1,` is matched by the optional
part of the second group. See the `*?` example in the [docs](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn’t make sense to say `\d{1}?`. 
   You want to match one digit, or none, do just say `\d?`.
2. So you could use `(.*)(\d?\,?\d{3}\.\d{2})`. 
   But that would match the `2019` in `City2019.00`. 
   (It would also match the `,243.56` in `City,234.56`,
   if you ever got malformed input like that.) 
   You want to match `NNN.NN`
   or `N,NNN.NN` —
   you either have `N,` or you don’t. 
   So try `(.*)((\d\,)?\d{3}\.\d{2})`,
   which makes `\d\,` (i.e., `N,`) a group
   and applies the `?` to it.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. However, this fails to capture the 1,550.00 in April5April5AnnualMembershipFee1,550.00 and the 2,199.75 in March31April1ToysRUsUptownBgcMakati2,199.75